# Better error messages from embedded Typescript in html pages in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

When embedding TypeScript in html pages in Angular 7, we often get unusable error messages such as:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'PersonName' of undefined
>   core.js:15724 message:"Cannot read property 'PersonName' of undefined"
>   stack:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'PersonName' of undefined\n
>
> at xxxx.push../xxxx/person.component.ts
>   .pages.setupDefaultValues (http://localhost:4200/main.js:22416:45)\n
>
> at xxx.push../xxxx/person.component.ts.ngOnInit
>   (http://localhost:4200/main.js:22409:14)\n

The root cause is: The embedded TS in the html page has referenced a value that is null.

The problem is: Which line is this on?  In this simple example, its easy to find the locations for PersonName, but other examples are not as simple.

I know that this issue can be side-stepped by changing

```
<h2>{{ page.PersonName }} </h2>
```

to

```
<h2>{{ page?.PersonName }} </h2>
```

But that simply hides the error.

What im looking for is:

1. A way to setup an error handler that will tell me if and when an
   error occurred.
2. How to enable a better error message that I can use to pinpoint the line number in the html file?

This was compiled with --aot and --prod DISABLED.

Any ideas?

**Updates:**

I found this interesting article

https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/catch-angular-template-errors-like-a-pro-or-how-i-create-angular-demo-e98694977911

That shows how the author was able to implement a system that provides better messages, but i dont see how it can be extrapolated to my problem.

One thing that is helpful is the use of the Angular Language Service

https://angular.io/guide/language-service

It provides a plugin to VScode to provide intelesense for TS in html files.

Once enabled, it identified missing variables that were referenced in my html!

This page summarizes lots of TypeScript errors and provides some ways to fix things, but does not help with my error

https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-debugging-tips-and-tricks

Comment: Usually I use a container with `*ngIf` like below `<section *ngIf="page">

all your other stuff here

</section>`

Answer (score 0):

Using the Angular Language service is the only technique that I found. It will give you a red squiggle in VSCode.

But it leaves a lot to be desired.